# Application Publish Help

Tags: apex, api, appexchange

I am planning to publish an app on AppEXchange but we have used API(Google Contact Api - Rest API). Should we have to go through web app scanner results.

Answer (score 0):

You would need BURP scanning if your application makes callout to external websites. [You can find potential question answered here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18504/burp-scanning-a-managed-package?rq=1).

[This is very good blog post written](http://www.fishofprey.com/2013/01/using-burp-suite-to-test-web-service.html) by Daniel on same topic.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce no longer provides licenses to BURP. Instead ZAP is the preferred tool. It should be used for testing and the results submitted.  More information is hwere - http://security.force.com/security/tools/webapp/zapbrowsersetup

Comment: How to test RestAPi on zap. Can you please provide instructions on how to do it ?